# After using Pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe the program cant find the correct txt file location

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm currently trying to convert my python program into an executable but when i do convert it and run the .exe file it throws the error, `No such file or directory: 'profiles.txt'`.

I'm trying to read and write to the text file based on user input. is there a way i can get my program to find the correct text file so I can get the exe file to work?

Comment: What is `profiles.txt`? It is a file that you need to provide to your program or is a file requested by a package/library or is a file that you create?

Comment: its a file i need to provide to my program, it stores users info when they enter it and saves it for next time so the GUI can display the information on the screen

Answer (score 0):

If your program depends of other files, you can include it in the program using the [Pyinstaller spec files](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle). Spec files contains all the instructions to create your program, including additional data files or missing modules that Pyinstaller cann't find. I strongly recommend you to use it.

A spec file looks like:

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=[ ('src/README.txt', 'myfiles') ],
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```

The files that you need to provide to your program are in `datas=`. In this example you will add the file `readme.txt` in the folder `src` of your pc to the folder `myfiles` in the bundled app.

Comment: my datas looks like this currently:              datas=[("/correctpath../profiles.txt", "dist")], but the code still isn't picking up the file and reading from it, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How does your python program call the file "profiles.txt"?

Comment: like this '    profiles = open("profiles.txt", "r")' ive also tried the direct path and it didn't work either.

Comment: Then, in the spec file I think should be `datas=[("/correctpath../profiles.txt", ".")]`. This saves the file in the root folder of the bundled app. You also can copy and paste the file in the bundled app to verify if your program works.